# NoMethodError when generating new view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, controller

I'm working on making a simple app that has users which can have many playlists. I'm trying to render the New view of a playlist but I'm getting this error:

```
NoMethodError in PlaylistsController#new
undefined method `playlist' for nil:NilClass

  def new
    @playlist = @user.playlist.new
  end
```

Here's some context:

EDIT: I uploaded the relevant parts of my code to a gist.github:

https://gist.github.com/izikperz/164eab76e64d375d9075

Playlist_controller.rb

```
class PlaylistsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_playlist, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
                :set_user

  # GET /playlists
  # GET /playlists.json
  def index
    @playlists = Playlist.all
  end

  # GET /playlists/1
  # GET /playlists/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /playlists/new
  def new
    @playlist = @user.playlist.new
  end

  # GET /playlists/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /playlists
  # POST /playlists.json
  def create
    @playlist = @user.playlists.new(playlist_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @playlist.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user.playlist, notice: 'Playlist was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @playlist }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        #format.json { render json: @playlist.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /playlists/1
  # PATCH/PUT /playlists/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @playlist.update(playlist_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @playlist, notice: 'Playlist was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @playlist }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @playlist.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /playlists/1
  # DELETE /playlists/1.json
  def destroy
    @playlist.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to playlists_url, notice: 'Playlist was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_user
      @user = User.find_by(params[:user_id])
    end
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_playlist
      @playlist = Playlist.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def playlist_params
      params.require(:playlist).permit(:user_id, :title, :img)
    end
end
```

in my routes.rb I have:

```
resources :users do
    resources :playlists
  end
```

My user.rb model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
  has_many :playlists
end
```

Playlist.rb model:

```
class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :playlist
    validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

My database schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20141105043809) do

  create_table "playlists", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "img"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", primary_key: "user_id", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "imgurl"
  end

end
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

#### The `@user` object in the `new` action is `nil`.

```
undefined method `playlist' for nil:NilClass
```

This is because params[:user_id] was not sent from your view.

Fix it by chaniging:

```
new_user_playlist_path(params[:user_id])
```

to:

```
new_user_playlist_path(user_id: params[:user_id])
```

---

After fixing that, another error will arise in the `new` action:

```
@playlist = @user.playlist.new
```

It should be pluralized as it is in your association:

```
@playlist = @user.playlists.new
#or
@playlist = @user.playlists.build
```

Or Simply ignore that:

```
@playlist = Playlist.new(user_id: @user.id)
```

Comment: is this how I would send it from my view?
<%= link_to 'New Playlist', new_user_playlist_path(params[:user_id])%>

Comment: yes, assuming that `params[:user_id]` contains the `user_id`

Comment: @user2804881 is it fixed?

Comment: I couldn't get it to work. Here's more of my code...can you please take a look? https://gist.github.com/izikperz/164eab76e64d375d9075

Comment: It's the same as yesterday. I've listed it in the gist above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64358/discussion-between-mohameddiaa27-and-user2804881).

Answer (score 0):

Since the ActiveRecord Association between User and Playlist is `:has_many` and `:belongs_to` these are many to many associations. This implies that one user has more than one playlists. The association will provide you with a instance method `@user.playlists` not `@user.playlist`. Try to use the plural version. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are sending `user_id` along with form so that

`@user = User.find_by(id: params[:user_id])` is not `nil`

and then change this

```
@playlist = @user.playlists.new
```